# What is $\sum_{i=1}^n i^2 \frac{CF_i}{CF_{Total}}$

Tags: duration

I know that $$\sum_{i=1}^n i \frac{CF_i}{CF_{Total}}$$ is Macaulay Duration, but what is $$\sum_{i=1}^n i^2 \frac{CF_i}{CF_{Total}}$$. I have given it a thought like it is a second moment of something and for a few internet search this has a correlation with Convexity. Is it just convexity if not, what is it ?

Answer (score 2):

The first expression is Macaulay Duration only if $CF_i$ is THE PRESENT VALUE of cash flow i, not the cash flow itself. A more explicit formula would be $\sum_i i \frac{PV(CF_i)}{PV_{Total}}$.

The second expression (with the same caveat) is the Macaulay Convexity, which is a little different from the Convexity that is commonly used nowadays.